# 18.04 NVIDIA MX230 graphics Can't change resolution on ASUS MX27A monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I bought notebook DELL Inspirion 5593 with Intel HD Graphics and NVIDIA MX230.

I have Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 [additional information about OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1NPw.png) and Windows 10 as well (dual boot).

When I connect my external monitor ASUS MX27A with max resolution 2560x1440 in Ubuntu setting for Devices/Monitor I have only 1920x1080 max resolution. I do get 2560x1440 @ 60 Hz in Windows.

I tried manually add new mode for resolution with xrandr:

```
cvt 2560 1440
```

> "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1440_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00
```

and I got this failure:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

but if I use smaller HZ value - 33 instead of 60 - it's working. But you know, 33 HZ is a hell, it's not possible for my eyes.

In Asus MX27A monitor manual there is a resolution table:

[image: table]

According to this table I should be able to use this resolution with 60Hz - **2560x1440@60Hz**

I've also checked HDMI port version of my notebook, it's 1.4b (new enough).

Comment: @K7AAY i have updated information

Comment: @K7AAY sorry for so late answer
it works fine with windows 10
also i tried with ubuntu 19 (cuz i have read a lot issues about intel 10 gen) but i also getting full hd maximum resolution

Comment: 1) Do you get 2560x1440 @ 60Hz with Ubuntu 19.10? 2) In Ubuntu 18.04, are you using version 440.82 of the NVIDIA drivers? https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/159360/

Comment: @K7AAY nope, either ubuntu 19 nor 440 driver

Answer (score 0):

Use the current version, 440.82, of the NVIDIA drivers to solve this problem. https://nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/159360

Comment: it didn't help :C

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the exact same issue and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606590/433175) worked for me.

Basically the problem seems to be that cvt is outputting the incorrect numbers, so you actually need to run

```
edid-decode /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid
```

(it might prompt you to install edid-decode first). Doing that should give you a correct modeline, namely by noting the clock (in MHz), then the two sets of four numbers, and the hsync and vsync. Now you can run your xrandr commands with these new numbers and it should work. You can also do some quick calculations to confirm that the numbers are for the refresh rate you want (see the linked answer for more details).